# Python configparser read config from S3 without downloading

Tags: python, amazon-s3, configparser

is there a way to read a .ini configuration file from s3 without downloading it?

What I have tried:

config.ini:

```
[DEFAULT]
test = test1
test1 = test2

[ME]
me = you
you = he
```

code:

```
import boto3
import io
import configparser

s3_boto = boto3.client('s3')
configuration_file_bucket = "mybucket"
configuration_file_key = "config.ini"
obj = s3_boto.get_object(Bucket=configuration_file_bucket, Key=configuration_file_key)

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()))
```

It returns [].

I have tried to make sure that

```
obj['Body'].read()
```

is returning well a binary with content of config.ini. This is working. It breaks somewhere further.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `read` method of `ConfigParser` takes a file name, and yet you're passing it a file object.

You can instead use the [`read_string`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.read_string) method so that you can pass to it the content returned by the `read` method of the `StreamingBody` object:

```
config.read_string(obj['Body'].read().decode())
```

Comment: I get an error: AttributeError: 'StreamingBody' object has no attribute 'readable'

Comment: Your comment that it has to be a binary stream had me look at the documentation. Finally, what worked is config.read_file(io.TextIOWrapper(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read())))

Comment: No need to use a file-like object then. The point of using a file-like object is to avoid having to use the `read` method that loads the entire file into memory. But apparently `StreamingBody` doesn't implemented all the necessary attributes to make it compatible with `TextIOWrapper`, in which case you can simply use the `read_string` method instead. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. Btw, the documentation of read() method says that it can take a bytes object. I have tried yesterday config.read(obj['Body'].read()), but it still didn't work. type(obj['Body'].read()) returns bytes. Do you know why it doesn't work?

Comment: That's because the documentation says that if it's a bytes object then it is treated as a filename, just as if it is a string.

Comment: @blhsing, could you explain a bit more `obj['Body'].read().decode()` ,
please?